# Git branch name in prompt

Tags: bash, git, gnu-screen

I am able to show the git branch name in the shell prompt. But whenever I am using screen I am  getting

```
bash: parse_git_branch: command not found
```

and git branch is not shown.
Please help me get this in the screen sessions also.

I have following in my .bash_profile.

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/
}

export PS1="[\W\$(parse_git_branch)]$ "
```

I don't have `.git-completion.bash`

**System specs:**

- OS: OSX 10.8.4
- Terminal & iTerm2
- Screen version: 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06

Comment: How are you customizing your prompt? Could you give your PS1 string?

Comment: Where is the `.git-completion.bash` file sourced in your main shell (i.e. without screen ?)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue when running under screen and was able to resolve by moving the definition of the `parse_git_branch()` function from `.bash_profile` to `.bashrc`.

Comment: It can be moved or copied from `.bash_profile` to `.bashrc`. I resolved this issue by copying the function.

Answer (score 5):

When you open your terminal, `.bash_profile` is executed and therefore `PS1` is defined. Then you execute screen, and screen reads the environment variable `PS1` which includes a call to `parse_git_branch` and tries to parse it. But, since screen didn't execute `.bash_profile` the function `parse_git_branch` is not defined inside screen.

Move the definition of `PS1` to `.bashrc` because both, screen and iTerm execute it.

Answer (score 3):

This is much simpler and avoids the unnecessary sed:

```
parse_git_branch () {

    while read -r branch; do
        [[ $branch = \** ]] && current_branch=${branch#* }
    done < <(git branch 2>/dev/null)

    [[ $current_branch ]] && printf ' [%s]' "$current_branch"

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `'` at the end of your sed statement:

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="[\W\$(parse_git_branch)]$ "
```

Othewerise, it seems to work for me in `bash-3.2`

Comment: unfortunately it is not working for me. Do I have to add something in the screenrc too?

Comment: are you still getting the "command not found" message? What else do you have in your .bash_profile? For fun, try putting a test function in your ``.bash_profile``  `` testFunc () {
 echo "test!"
}`` and calling it.

Comment: I resolved it. once I am in screen I use 'source ~/.bash_profile'. It brings all the settings back. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have the need in my mac to run this AND my .bashrc file otherwise after a restart they are not applied. I will try and keep these noted somewhere...thanks for everyone contributing :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in OS X High Sierra when switching to root or when starting to `ssh-agent /bin/bash` I resolved it to put it in `/etc/bashrc` with check if i am root

```
if [[ $UID == 0 ]]; then
        PS1="\[\e[1;31;40m\]\u@\h \W\[\e[0m\]\$ "
else
        parse_git_branch() {
                git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
        }
        PS1="\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
fi
```